# Content-Type application/octet-stream or something more specific?

Tags: rest, http

I writing an end point to accept binary data. I see in [Google's API for uploading photos](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/upload-media#uploading-bytes), they use `application/octet-stream` for the `Content-Type` and custom header `X-Goog-Upload-Content-Type` for the MIME type. I am leaning towards just asking for the MIME type, e.g. `audio/wav` or `audio/mp3` in the Content-Type header. Is this an acceptable approach or should all raw binary uploads use `application/octet-stream`?

Answer (score 0):

No. "application/octet-stream" essentially means "I don't know the type". If you know the type, by all means specify it.